# 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'count'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to loop through an (as I would interpret) array by `arrayname.count` like:

```
if var storedToDoItems: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") {  
        toDoItems = []

        for var i = 0; storedToDoItems.count; i++ {
            toDoItems.append(storedToDoItems[i] as NSString)
        }
    }
```

and receive the error in the title marked by `storedToDoItems.count`. I'm populating first `storedToDoItems` like this:

```
...
    toDoItems.append(tb_toDoItem.text)

    let fixedToDoItems = toDoItems

    // Store items
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fixedToDoItems, forKey: "toDoItems")

    // Save the stored stuff
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store an array to the user defaults, you should try to cast it to an array when you extract it.

If `toDoItems` is defined as an array of strings `[String]`, then you just have to use optional binding combined with optional cast, and just copy the extracted array to `toDoItems`:

```
if let storedToDoItems: [String] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {
    toDoItems = storedToDoItems
}
```

Being an array a struct, i.e. a value type, it is assigned by copy, so when assign `storedToDoItems` to `toDoItems`, a copy of it is created and assigned - so you don't need to manually add each element individually.

Your code instead has 2 errors:

- you have defined `storedToDoItems` as an optional `AnyObject`, and optionals don't have a `count` property.
- even if it is not defined as optional, `AnyObject` doesn't have a `count` property as well. It's irrelevant that the actual type stored in the variable is an array, the variable is declared as `AnyObject` and that is how is treated by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you both guys so easy and no loop needed! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell what's inside:

```
toDoItems = [String]()
if let storedToDoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {
    for item in storedToDoItems {
        toDoItems.append(item)
    }
}
```

and even shorter:

```
toDoItems = [String]()
if let storedToDoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {
    toDoItems = storedToDoItems
}
```

Comment: The first was just a "corrected" version of the OP's code regarding the declarations. The second would be the right one. The initialization IS necessary since after the if it is either empty or (if present) contains the user defaults. Alternatively one could place the empty assignment in an else statement. Anyhow. this is not inside a heavy loop and thus performance is not of any interest here.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this  Bold line will work for you hopefully

if var toDoStored: [String] = **NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoSaved") as? [String]{**

```
         tblItems = []

        for var i = 0; i < toDoStored.count ; ++i  {
         tblItems.append(toDoStored[i] as NSString)
        }

    }
```